# Unable to run multiple Jobs in apache flink Parallelly

Tags: apache-flink

1) I have installed Apache Flink in my local machine (Ubuntu 16.04). Developed a java programs, created Jar files and trying to run them as a jobs in Flink web front end. I am able to run the job individually, but couldn't able to run multiple jobs parallel.
Please let me know if any configuration has to be modified, so that i can run them simultaneously.
2) Unable to run the flink job which is having multiple tasks (>500 task in a single job) Getting following exceptions:

```
(a) network.partition.PartitionNotFoundException (org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.partition.PartitionNotFoundException)
```

```
(b) rest.handler.taskmanager.TaskManagerDetailsHandler (org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.handler.taskmanager.TaskManagerDetailsHandler  - Implementation error: Unhandled exception)
```

```
(c) heap memory exception
```

Please let me know how to overcome these and what are the necessary configuration needed to run the job.

Tried to increase memory to 2048.